# React native application starting performance issue

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native developement and currently have performance issue when user launches app. 
It takes like 5-10 second on both Nexus 6P emulator and my Samsung tablet to render content of the application.

Currently I have tab navigator as main component and three stack navigators inside of tab navigator and seems like  react native tries to mount\render all of those components at once. Can you please tell me how I can solve this issue to create smoother user experience with my app ? Because all of my components are pretty lightweight and it's strange that I have any performance issues.

Comment: do you have a lot of console.logs in your app? I had the same issue on android and when I removed the logs the app started normally.

Comment: I think the problem that you have is just because you are on the develop mode. If you publish it and install the apk package it will be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

This slowness is natural because you are in the develop mode and you may showing some consoles on the console log. The problem will be disappeared if you publish the app and install the apk you will not have that problem. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Virtual Device Manager, select your AVD, select "Edit this AVD", in the new window (Virtual Device Configuration), goto Emulated Performance > Graphics and select the "Software (GLS)"

This may enhance your performance issues, it worked well for me